# I need more grace period before awarding a bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounty, grace-period

I have posted [my first bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675818/non-compatible-function-addresses-between-gcc-compiler-flags-and-symbol-table) and had two answers the last day. The bounty is off and I have only 24 hours to award an answer. The problem is I need more time to be able to test the proposed solution, simply because I am not full time on this task and I don't have access to the features now.

It would be nice to be able to increase the grace period up to one week, in order to have the opportunity to evaluate the answers.

Comment: It really would take a week to test? You may not be full time on the project, but the people who answered are giving up their *spare* time to help you. You don't think it's fair to test and/or reward their solutions promptly rather than keep them waiting a week?

Comment: I don't think we are in a day to day business here. I don't understand your position. Of course, this test takes less than 20 minutes, but you have to be in to do it.

Comment: @lalebarde I wonder. If bounty questions provide important code for the project, will your company license the product created through that code under CC-BY-SA 3.0, as required by CC-BY-SA 3.0? This license allows free copying and reuse, subject to attribution and similar downstream licensing. Were you aware?

Comment: This code will not belong to any product, it is just for test purpose.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - some testing takes a week and longer. I think you are confusing the common case of "it compiles, ship it" and the disposable model of "abandon last week's version" with comprehensive/disciplined testing and evaluation. For example, Crypto++ has a [test script from hell](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh) that takes thee to five days to run on an Internet of Things device. We [can't make it run faster](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37047472), despite my sincerest efforts to speed it up while avoiding OOM kills.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - you also assume the only tester is the original poster and he/she has the hardware required on hand. I think the assumptions are flawed. I often [put out a call for testers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/OSCzlJ2orzM) and sometimes I don't get any responses.

Comment: @jww the purpose of Stack Overflow is not to serve as a flexible part of a project management schedule that sees code go from development to testing to shipping. It's to answer specific questions. A question of "will this meet all my project's requirements in the long run" is out of scope and off topic. If you need that don't rely on volunteers; hire someone.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - I'm guessing you performed the misdirection into project management because your position is untenable. Good luck with that position. I've never seen anyone take the position that Stack Overflow is ***not*** for finding answers to problems for code not meant for production.

Answer (score 16):

While I appreciate the predicament you find yourself in, extending the grace period isn't an option.

Next time, try to have a test rig set up *before* you offer the bounty (or better yet, before you ask the question) - this'll greatly reduce the time and effort required for validating answers, and probably help you write a better question as well.

Comment: You have not understood my question I am afraid. It is not a question of preparing a test which is ready, it is a question to be in and be able to pass it. I can access the web and email, but not my lab now. I am not a guy in his lab all the day and every day. I have to move a lot to customers.

Comment: Some folks need a longer grace period for testing. I'm in the same boat as the OP - testing a particular change set (based on a hack) means 3 to 4 days of testing. Its not clear to me why Stack Overflow objects to allowing additional time for the Bounty Award/Grace Period. Naively, it seems like there's no difference between 1 day and 1 week in the big picture. Why does Stack Overflow object to providing more time for the Award/Grace once the Bounty has concluded?

Comment: So you're expecting folks to provide an answer in 7 days that you can't test in less than 3, @jww? That seems... Optimistic.